# How to display a view without using a page template - drupal 7

Tags: views, theming, 7

So on a drupal site I am working on the client has a page where they have a view without a page template applied to it, and now the client wants to change the url of that page. As soon as I change the url of the view it applies the page template to the view. Obviously this was hard-coded in by url by the person who originally built the site, however, I have no idea how they did it. So i'm hoping someone on here has had a similar experience or knows how to make a view without a page template being applied to it.

Comment: What tpl.php files exist in the theme that have "page" in the name?

Comment: page.tpl.php, maintenance-page.tpl.php, page--customerror--404.tpl.php

Comment: hm... how about anything in template.php that is specific to the path of the view?

Comment: url for the view is "www.site.com/solutions", found this in the template but it's prob not related.                       if ($node->type == 'solution') {
    $variables['myvariable'] = "some text here";
  }

Comment: I don't understand "url path is solution for the view". What happens if you grep the old path in your codebase, does anything come up?

Comment: sorry reworded, basically that if statement is the only thing related to the url for that view

Answer (score 1):

You can create a block view and display it anywhere in the code.

If your text format allow you to use PHP code you can insert a views anywhere in your website by adding something like this.

```
  <?php
    $block1 = "Name_Of_The_View";
    print views_embed_view($block1);
  ?>
```

And this will print a view inside of a node without using a page template. The beauty about this is that you can add HTML around this without using the block module.

For more information I will recommend you to read this documentation page [Placing the contents of a block in any location](https://www.drupal.org/node/26502)